# django-filter return empty queryset on invalid query param

Tags: django, django-filter

Is there a way to make a `FilterSet` return an empty queryset if an invalid query param is given? For example, in `people/?name=joe&asdf=asdf`, `name` is a valid column on model but `asdf` is irrelevant. Currently django-filter returns all objects.

I can manually check if all of the parameters are valid but I was wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose your model name is `People`

```
if parameter not in [ f.name for f in People._meta.fields ]:
    return People.objects.none()
```

You can check for each parameter is match model fields. Return and empty model queryset if your `GET`parameter is invalid.

**Due OP comment:**

If query parameter is invalid a `FieldError` exception should be raised:

```
try:
    qs=People.objects.filter(**request.GET)
except FieldError:
    qs=People.objects.none()
```

Comment: It returns none queryset when in `request.GET` will be accessors to related fields, for example `some_fk_field__name=asdf`

Comment: How about giving the user an error response on invalid input? Very handy for other developers..

Comment: @Stephan, this is just a code snippet. Obviously you should to complete in order to get a comfortable user experience. You are asking for a different subject than OP, any way take a look to django message framework.

Comment: @danihp You want to raise an ValidationError. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#validationerror  this way other developers can get an understandable resonse.

Comment: @Stephan, nice appointment. I do not include it on answer because is only for api environments (they are still people coding without REST layer). Any case, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is not `django-filter` problem.

```
filter_obj = filter_class(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
```

You can do this in your views while `get_queryset`:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    if all(map(lambda x: any(x == f for f in self.filter_class.declared_filters), self.request.GET)):
        queryset = self.model.objects.all()
    else:
        queryset = self.model.objects.none()

    return queryset
```

Comment: It's funny, 5 houres unanswered and we both post at same time. What kind of [distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution#Discrete_probability_distribution) is this.

Comment: @danihp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-filter is more funny, OP asked three times in a row, and each question has less tags than previous for one